# i18n-active_record and protected_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

When I am trying add new translation:

```
I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new.store_translations(:encoding, :key => value)
```

I have following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation: locale, key, value
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I made up patch concern:

```
module TranslationPatch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    if defined?(ProtectedAttributes)
      attr_accessible :missing,:locale,:key,:value
    end
  end
end
```

and included it in locale.rb file:

```
require 'i18n/backend/active_record'
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new

I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation.send(:include,TranslationPatch)
```